# Audioplayer doesn't stop from other view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In first view i create audio player and load from the begining

```
@interface SplashViewController : UIViewController
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *mp3;
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self viewDidAppear:YES];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sooner" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSError *error;
mp3 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[mp3 setNumberOfLoops:-1];
[mp3 setVolume:1.0];
[mp3 play];
}
```

Ok, ihave many views and i happy that musik play always not matter in what views I work. But I need stop music in other (my SettingView). I have next code in SettingView, but I have no result - musik play and play, and don't want to stop

```
@class SplashViewController;
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) SplashViewController *splashViewController;

________________________________________________________
#import "SplashViewController.h"
...
@implementation SettingsViewController
@synthesize pauseMusik; //UISwitch
@synthesize splashViewController = _splashViewController;
...
-(IBAction)playPauseMusik:(id)sender
{
if(!self.splashViewController)
    self.splashViewController = [[SplashViewController 
alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController" bundle:nil];
if (pauseMusik.on) {
    [self.splashViewController.mp3 play];
}
else
    [self.splashViewController.mp3 stop];}
```

Where I did mistake?

Comment: Try: 1) explicitly setting the mp3 property by using [self setMp3: ...]; 2) use a number greater than 0 as the number of loops 3) use [_splashViewController.mp3 stop];

Comment: 2 and 3 don't help, about 1 - I don't understand^ what I must do =(

Comment: Replace the line mp3 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error]; with [self setMp3:[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created separate class AudioViewController, and create a method:

```
@implementation AudioViewController
@synthesize mp3;
static AudioViewController * sharedPlayer = NULL;
+ (AudioViewController *) sharedPlayer {
if ( !sharedPlayer || sharedPlayer == NULL ) {
    sharedPlayer = [AudioViewController new];
}
return sharedPlayer;
}
```

And created method for play/pause:

```
-(void)player:(BOOL)playPause
{
if (playPause==YES)
   [mp3 play];
else [mp3 stop]; }
```

Where mp3 is

```
AVAudioPlayer *mp3;
```

So now I can simply play/stop musik from any ViewController with

```
#import "AudioViewController.h"
...
[[AudioViewController sharedplayer]player:YES]//for playing
[[AudioViewController sharedplayer]player:NO]//for stoping
```

There is a decision for my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSNotificationCenter. For example.. your IBaction (from SettingController):

```
if.. {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"actionChangedStop" object:nil];
}
else
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"actionChangedPlay" object:nil];
}
```

NSNotificationCenter sends "broadcasts" a message to the entire application.

Now we need an observer.. in SplashController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 ..
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(actionChangedStop)
                                                 name:@"actionChangedStop"
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(actionChangedPlay)
                                                 name:@"actionChangedPlay"
                                               object:nil];
...
```

..
 a given method is called..

```
-(void)actionChangedStop{[audioPlayer stop];}
-(void)actionChangedPlay{[audioPlayer play];}
```

.. and Voila

Comment: Thnaks, but I found the decision